# What does this `sp' notation mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, spectral-theory

I'm reading a paper called ["On local spectral radius"](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/118306/CasPestMat_112-1987-2_6.pdf). Throughout there is this weird notation. In particular they say things like

**Lemma 2:** Let $N$ be a subset of a Banach space $X$. Then
$$  \sup \Big\{  r(K,h) : h \in N \Big\} =  \sup \Big\{  r(K,h) : h \in sp(N) \Big\}  $$

At first I thought `sp' referred to spectrum, but I'm not familiar with any notions of spectrum of a set. Another usage is $sp\{ A^n x : n \geq 0 \}$.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"sp" is not a notation for the spectrum. "sp" means linear span.

The usual notation for the spectrum is $\sigma$.